# How to avoid the continuous downcasting in this case?

Tags: interfaces, abstract-class, type-casting

I have an abstract class `Dog` and multiple subclasses (`Beagle`, `Labrador`, `Bulldog`...) extendig it. I have a `DogHouse` that can store a `Dog`.

My problem is that when I put for example a `Beagle` into a `DogHouse` like `doghouse.addDog(beagle)` and then take it out with `doghouse.getDog()`, this method gives me the beagle as a `Dog`, but I want to get my `Beagle` back.

`DogHouse` has many more methods, they all give me `Dogs`, but I work with specific dogs in my application. Does it mean that I always have to downcast?

---

**Update:**

I'm using TypeScript and can change any part of the code so my options are practically endless. What I don't understand:

Imagine you have two dog schools. Knowing that different breeds of dogs are capable of very different things and need different care and training, dog school 1 is specialized in `Greyhound`s, while the other is training let's say `Bulldog`s only.

There is a company selling `DogHouse`s. They say that their product is compatible with any kind of `Dog`, so both dog schools decide to buy from them.

A trainer at dog school 1 tells a Greyhound to run very fast: `greyhound.runVeryFast();` - something that only greyhounds can do. It works.

Then, she sends the greyhound into a DogHouse: `doghouse.addDog(greyhound);` - which works too.

After the dog could rest enough, she calls him and tells him to run very fast again: `doghouse.getDog().runVeryFast();` - It does not work.

She turns to the company selling the `DogHouse`s to complain what a stupid house they've built that a dog forgets in it to which breed he belongs. *"Why do I have to tell the dog (cast him) that he is a `Greyhound` every time he comes out of his house?"*

The company answers *"Sorry madam, maybe we can build a new house using generics."* But then the lady answers: *"And will it then accept `Cat`s" too? I only want a house for `Dog`s."*

So my question is: How to build a proper `DogHouse`?

Comment: Do you control the DogHouse implementation, can you change it or pick other class for same purpose?

Comment: Yes, I can modify anything

Comment: I'd encourage you to read the answer by Kilian Foth - it is important to understand what's said there. But for us to be able to help you in a more specific way, can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Specifically, what are you using your DogHouse for? How many dog instances can be placed in there. Is it just a container, or does it have some behavior associated with it (some nontrivial mehtods)? What are you doing with each concrete dog class that cannot be expressed through the interface provided by the Dog base class? (Consider adding these points to your question.)

Comment: Thanks, I added some more info to describe what confuses me.

Comment: That's quite a picturesque clarification :) Anyway, from what you described, you *can* use generics *with generic constraints*, as described in Karel Coudijzer's answer - the code there seems to be C#, but TypeScript supports generic constraints as well; see the Generic Constraints section [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: "then take it out with doghouse.getDog()" - that's the point: do you ever ask the dog house to return your dog? Rather, you'd tell your dog "Leave the doghouse, come here!".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You  could make use of generics and create a DogHouse of T.

```
class DogHouse<T>
    where T : Dog
{
    private T dog

    T getDog() { return this.dog; }

    void addDog(T dog) { this.dog = dog; }
}

var house = new DogHouse<Bulldog>();
var dog = new Bulldog();
house.addDog(dog);

Bulldog bulldog = house.getDog();
```

Comment: I like this approach but you're missing the using code that gets you back the dog as a bulldog without any casting.

Comment: +1, if OP needs *different* doghouses, but *only one kind of dog* per house, then this is the way to go.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that what candied_orange is getting at is that this is fine if the DogHouse itself has no behavior that depends on the concrete type of Dog, but if it does, then it won't work because within DogHouse you can only write code against the interface of Dog. Only external code can access the interface of Bulldog.

Comment: @max630 that's not getting it back. That's putting it in. All I'm saying is the answer would be better if we saw `getDog()` being used without any casting. It's a bit hard to write a clear example while using `var`

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: If you want `DogHouse` to "have behavior that depends on the concrete type of Dog," then you need subclasses of `DogHouse` for each concrete type, which may mean we need to have a side discussion about covariance and contravariance.  That naturally leads to questions such as "Why is it so complicated?" and "Why must every language do it differently?"  It's probably easier to move that logic into the `Dog` interface and do dispatch via `Dog`'s polymorphism instead.  Then you can avoid that whole mess of toxic nonsense.

Comment: @Kevin: True, but what I wrote that comment before the OP edited his post, so it was unclear what is it that the OP was trying to achieve (so at that point I wasn't sure if this is the right advice or not, which is why I aked him to clarify (the question's comment section)). Turns out, the OP has considered generics but was concerned that a generic DogHouse "will [...] accept Cats too", so I pointed out that generic constraints take care of that (and that these are available in TypeScript, the language the OP uses).

Comment: @candied_orange I mistyped actually. ok, now it's there

Answer (score 14):

Ask yourself: **why** do you want to downcast?

The declaration "`DogHouse` contains `Dog`s" says exactly that: you can be sure of dealing with a `Dog`, nothing more. If you want beagles and labadors to do different things in the same situation, then you should override those methods (e.g. `bark()`) in each subclass and simply call `dog.bark()`.

If you can't arrange things that way in your language (for instance, if you need multiple dispatch to distinguish between appropriate actions), then subclassing is not the right way to structure your data model. If you *must* know the concrete type of an object in order to use it effectively, then there is no point in storing them in a generic container.

Comment: Can you resolve that by creating serializable classes?

Answer (score 1):

> A trainer at dog school 1 tells a Greyhound to run very fast:
>   greyhound.runVeryFast(); - something that only greyhounds can do. It
>   works.

This is a design smell and the base of the problems your running into. This is a violation of LSP: base and derived classes should have the same capabilities.

In your case, every dog (or none) should have a RunVeryFast method and only their implementations may vary.

By following the LSP, you can be sure that every dog you fetch from the doghouse has a RunVeryFast() method.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, because if it's correct what you're saying then I have made multiple mistakes in my design. For other dogs however, `runVeryFast` wouldn't make any sense, there could be no implementation there at all, so what should I do? Is this where interfaces come into the picture?

Comment: There’s a principle called “composition over inheritance“ (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Comment: In short the principle says that your classes should hold references to other classes that contain the desired behavior. In your case Dog could have a IRunBehavior and when you create an instance of a Greyhound you pass in a RunVeryFast of type IRunBehavior.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case in a project where only on kind of “dog” is of special interest. Then I have factored all the common behavior into the parent class (sorting, name etc.) and built out only the interesting type with a lot more capabilities. This of course require check for is-of-type at strategic places and then branch out to analyzing the interesting “dog” with a downcast. This of course has limitation on future extendability but in my case I think I understand the problem domain well enough to say it is The right thing. Of course this goes against a lot of best practice but if you are very certain you can live with the limitations it may be simpler than injecting particular interfaces or making all dogs capable of responding to all methods.

The point is that if you can’t deal with most cases at the generic dog level then the inheritance idea has limited value. But then if you can and then need a few specials that require type check and downcast it may be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C allows a type "`kindof <Dog>`". If the getter method returns "`kindof <Dog>`" instead of "Dog", then the result can be assigned to a variable containing a reference to Dog or any subclass without cast. And any method calls are allowed that are implemented by Dog or any subclass. So you can write `[dogHouse.dog runVeryFast]` which is only implemented by Greyhound. The compiler accepts it. There will be a runtime error if the dog in the doghouse is not a Greyhound (or some other dog implementing runVeryFast).

This is not typesafe. But it is better than casting, which would allow casting to "SiameseCat". Neither assignment to a SiameseCat object nor `[dogHouse.dog catchMouse]` would compile.

Unlike the solution with generic types, DogHouse can contain *any* Dog.

(It is also possible to have a class DogHouse parameterised on some kind of Dog, which would be typesafe, but would have incompatible DogHouse objects for each kind of Dog).